# Is "to call someone out" in the sense of "to criticize/accuse/shame publicly" a new use?

Tags: word-usage, semantic-shift, social-media

Using "to call out" in the sense described is linked to heightened awareness of social justice and the use of social media. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancel_culture) specifically links the origin of the cultural phenomenon to an incident in 2014.

While public reactions in the age of social media can be swifter and more forceful than they used to be, social media are not a necessary prerequisite for public shaming.

Has this use of "to call out" indeed emerged only in the past couple of years?

As an aside, I'd also be curious how one might find that out. "To call out" is a common term. How would one go about finding specific uses without the resources of a dictionary publisher who pays linguists for such research?

Comment: @DjinTonic Well, while the proposed duplicate covers "call [someone] (on something)" as from 1940s, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=call+him+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccall%20him%20out%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccall%20him%20out%3B%2Cc0) seems to show that, yup, something's going on right now. (Most of those older entries are unrelated usages, like "God called him out of the grave," or refer to calling up troops.

Answer (score 1):

As the duplicate question alludes to, the OED's first citation for this sense is from 1981.

**call out** [under *call*, Phrasal Verbs]

> Originally and chiefly *U.S.* To expose or identify (a person) as
> acting in a dishonest or otherwise unacceptable manner; to challenge
> or confront. Frequently with *on*.
>
> 1981   *Akwesasne Notes* (N.Y.) Autumn 12/3   The military had..tried
> to cover up the incident. This..Military commander..had been
> responsible during the case of the Elder Lester Athars and so the
> people now were openly calling him out as an assassin, a murderer.
>
> 2013   G. Albin *Altered* iv. 38   I dislike how he speaks to Greta.
> But there's no time to call him out on it. OED

> To publicly criticize or fault (someone)
>
> *The FDA will have to start forcing companies to be transparent and call them out on it when they're not.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call%20out)

> **call someone out, call out someone** (phrasal verb)
>
> *North American* Draw critical attention to someone's unacceptable actions or behaviour.
>
> *People were calling him out for his negative comments* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/call_out)

Comment: It is probably worth noting that similar expressions have a much earlier usage: ***Call someone out of their name (v.)*** 
(US black) to insult through name-calling.

1938 - Showdown’ in Real Western Nov. *Johnny Straight had called him out of his name; had asked for a settlement.*

Comment: ***Call: to blame.***

1912 [US] H.G. van Campen ‘Our Theatrical Boarding House’ in L.A. Herald 10 Dec. 10/4: ‘*Ain’t you the gent who called me for keepin’ all the keepin’ all the pictures in the theater trunk, an’ when I put ’em out you snap at me’.*

Comment: @user66974  Also, the meaning of *to demand* is very old; and to *call someone* in poker and its use in other card games.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search through Google Books for variations on this phrase, such as "to call out," "call them out on," etc.  Here's some of what I found, including an apparent use of it in the sense you are talking about at least as far back as 1985.  I'm limited on time or else I would look more.

2005: [image]
[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bankruptcy_Abuse_Prevention_and_Consumer/Ti33L2ICI4MC?hl=en&gbpv=1)

1999:[image]
[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Democracy_Diversity_Dialogue/HGsfAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)

1985: [image]
[Source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Vigilante_Justice/mEkcjxiV0cQC?hl=en&gbpv=0)

Also, it never occurred to me where the phrase "to call out" came from, but in my search, I found several references to tennis, where people talk about "calling [a ball] out," meaning, "declaring that it is 'out'" per the rules of the game.

[image]